Probability Convention in Discrete Examples
I have this simple example that involves tossing two tetrahedral die. Let the event of tossing the first die be $X:=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and the event of tossing the second die $Y:=\{1,2,3,4\}$. The excercise says determine the probability of the particular event whose outcome has the first die landing a value of $1$.
I see in the textbook I am using the convention for writing probability being $\mathbb{P}(X=1)$. However, i am confused here; why is $X$ (a set) being assigned a value of $1$. What I did instead is defined a set $A:=\{{(x\in X,y\in Y)\mid x=1}\}$, and instead I wrote $\mathbb{P}(A)$.

My question is (1) why do we write $\mathbb{P}(X=\text{value})$ and (2) is the way I defined the event and denoted the probability mathematically valid?

Thank you in advance.

Just checking: Did your text actually use the notation $X:={1,2,3,4}$?

The $X$ in the text is not a set, but rather a random variable.

@JonathanZ Indeed, $X$ was defined as a set as you have wrote it.

I am new to probability theory, does the $X$ in $\mathbb{P}(X=1)$ hold a special meaning in general? All I know is that when $X$ is defined as a subset of a sample space, it is automatically the event in question. @SeanRoberson

In rigorous treatments, capital letters like $X, Y, Z, \ldots$ are called random variables. In courses for social science students, we don't really attach this meaning to it. I'll write a detailed answer later, but I suggest reading on what a random variable is to gain a bit of understanding.

alright will do, thank you very much! @SeanRoberson
